# How successful are current metadata implementations in achieving its objectives

Tags: metadata, comparison, iso-19115

Metadata infrastructure is well established as an essential practice within the GIS community.  Quoting from the [FGDC](http://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/metadata-business-case):

> Metadata helps people who use geospatial data find the data they need and determine how best to use it. Metadata supports producers in locating and using their own data resources and data consumers in locating and using data resources produced by others.

In your experience how effectively do current standards actually help to achieve these objectives?  I am particularly interested in analysis of ISO 19115:2003 and how it compares to over methods of capturing this kind of information.

Comment: There appear to be two questions here, one is an analysis of ISO 19115 as a metadata standard in general, compared to other standards.  The other is the more general question of whether Geospatial metadata is any use. [FGDC endorse](https://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/geospatial-metadata-standards) ISO 19115 and ISO 19139 standards so is the question asked from the view point of whether it is worth changing to a standard based on ISO 19115?